# WordPress - how to create hidden admin panel page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

All these functions attach options page to left menu:

```
add_menu_page(), 
remove_menu_page(), 
add_submenu_page(), 
remove_submenu_page(), 
add_dashboard_page(), 
add_posts_page(), 
add_media_page(), 
add_links_page(), 
add_pages_page(), 
add_comments_page(), 
add_theme_page(), 
add_plugins_page(), 
add_users_page(), 
add_management_page(), 
add_options_page()
```

I want to create an options page for top admin bar (not just custom link). Any ideas on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The [Enhance Admin Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/enhance-admin-bar/) plugin seems to be the solution you're looking for.

It essentially adds numerous useful options for WordPress Admin Bar. You can then manage options from your left menu.